# Label linked to a text box value

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, label

Good morning,
I am editing an User Form on VBA Excel and I would like to show an alert if the user insert a certain value in a text box.
I wrote this code:

```
If txtbox.Value < 0 Then
lbl_Alert.Visible= True
Else
lbl_alert.Visible=False
End IF
```

The code works properly but once the alert appears if I change the value in the text box it doesn't disappear.
What string should I add to my script to let the label disappear when I change the text box value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your code under the textbox_change event

Following works fine

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Me.TextBox1.Value < 0 Then
        Me.Label1.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.Label1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a sub (into your UserForm module, or in a regular module but with the `Public` declaration), like this :

```
Public Sub AlertDisplay()
    If UserForm1.txtbox.Value < 0 Then
        UserForm1.lbl_alert.Visible = True
    Else
        UserForm1.lbl_alert.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

And then call that sub into your `Private Sub TextBox_Change` (double click on that textbox to access it easily), just by adding a line : `AlertDisplay`